# Get vertice list of a polygon shape body

Tags: java, libgdx

How do you get a list of vertices for a specific polygon body in libgdx?

Like this :

```
public Array<Vector2> getVerts(Body body){
    Array<Vector2>verts = null;

    // can't find how to look them up properly anywhere

    return verts;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @James Webster's code:

```
Array<Vector2> verts = new Array<Vector2>();
Fixture f = body.getFixtureList().get(0);
PolygonShape s = f.shape;

// this is needed to temporarily keep the vertex, getVertex is a void method
Vector2 tmp = new Vector2();
for (int i = 0; i < s.getVertexCount(); i++) {
    // fill tmp with the vertex
    s.getVertex(i, tmp));
    verts.add(new Vector2(tmp));
}
```

Comment: Can the person who downvoted this explain the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked with LibGDX, but I have worked with Box2D and looking at the API, I'd suggest:

```
//Assuming only 1 fixture per body and a polygon shape


Array<Vector2>verts = new Array<Vector2>();
Fixture f = body.getFixtureList().get(0);
PolygonShape s = f.shape;
for (int i = 0; i < s.getVertexCount(); i++)
{
    verts.add(s.getVertex(i, /*I couldn't figure out what this param is supposed to be*/));
}
```

<sub>This was typed without an IDE, watch out for blatant errors! I haven't done Java in a long time either.</sub>