# How to get vertices from polygon

Tags: libgdx

I am using polygon for collision detection. Now i am trying to do a bit more complex collisions and for that i would need to get every polygon vertex as Vector2. I have searched trough the web and only thing i can find are with PolygonBody ([Get vertice list of a polygon shape body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098779/get-vertice-list-of-a-polygon-shape-body))

Only useful methods i can find in libgdx API are getTransformedVertices() and area(), but i dont know what to do with that data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `com.badlogic.gdx.math.Polygon` talking about polygon or you using meshes as polygons?

In first case you could do something like this:

```
Array<Vector2> getPolygonVertices(Polygon polygon) {
    float[] vertices = polygon.getTransformedVertices();

    Array<Vector2> result = new Array<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length/2; i++) {
        float x = vertices[i * 2];
        float y = vertices[i * 2 + 1];
        result.add(new Vector2(x, y));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Solution for meshes is pretty the same except of you should make some extra magic extracting x and y for each vertex (it depends on mesh attributes).

Comment: You welcome! I would recommend you make some pool optimization on vectors in case you need to call such method frequently.

Comment: well i have already done it. Instead of Vectors i have created ArrayList with floats, so that did avoid casting to Vector2. But it wont even matter becouse hittests happens not more than 2 times in 10 seconds and on most 2 polygons.